# PowerShell script for get application pool account and which application pool name, and its IIS site

Tags: 2013, powershell, iis7

Using SharePoint 2013 PowerShell, there is any script for getting application pool account and which application pool name, and its IIS site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes these information can be obtained by using below script:

```
Get-SPServiceApplication | ForEach-Object { $_.ApplicationPool}
```

Which will list out all the application pool names with its Identity

Answer (score 0):

We can get these by simple PowerShell command

```
Get-SPServiceApplicationPool
```